# How to aggregate minutely data to hourly after 90 days?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to average out minutely data to hourly after a certain time period. For that what will be the query.

The query structure is -

```
   GET ml_test_meters-2019_6/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "host-status.meta.current-time": {
              "gte": 1549611907552,
              "lte": 1549654551498,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "host-status.meta.current-time",
        "interval": "1h",
        "time_zone": "US/Central",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "host-status.name.keyword",
            "size": 500,
            "order": {
              "1": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "host-status.status-properties.status-detail.total-cpu-stat-iowait"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the possible solution ? I would like to insert the new data into the same index later on and delete minutely data.

Comment: Rollups does just this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/data-rollups-in-elasticsearch-you-know-for-saving-space.  If you do not want to the rollups plugin, then you will have to create some mechanism to take that aggregated data and put it in a different index that you included in your more general queries.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent For now can I get the mechanism ?

Comment: Elastic Search Rollups is an X-Pack feature and it is under the Basic License, so it is free. The API was released in 6.3, the UI for rollups (to aid in management, etc.) was released in 6.5. As for writing your own process (if using Rollups is not an option), it would probably have to be outside of Elasticsearch.